# Hint for a combinatorial statement for counting triangles

Tags: combinatorics, triangles, recreational-mathematics

[image]

I know it is asking me to prove it works for the total number of triangles. I notice a pattern which is $$T_n = n^3$$ but this doesn't seem to help me in anyway.

Edit: I also notice that the lines increase by 2 each time, creating 3 more intersections each time.

Comment: @user71207 u want to knw how $n^3$ is your answer or want to prove your formula of combination given below and FYI it is so easy u should try more before asking here

Comment: Want to prove your formula of combination given below. Actually, I do understand it more after thinking properly about it. I have explained the first section [2n+1]C3, but and still struggling with the -2[n+1]C3
I assume this is misusing the cases where you may select 3 points in a straight line thus making a line and not a triangle

Comment: yeah, I'm not really sure about the  -2[n+1]C3 part

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Note that every triangle in $T_n$ has at least one of the vertices of the base angles.

Besides, every triangle can be determined by exactly 3 lines in $T_n$. However, if you choose 3 lines intersecting at one point, you will not get a triangle.

Based on these facts, you can either write it down as $\displaystyle\binom{2n+1}3-2\binom{n+1}{3}$ or  $\displaystyle2\binom{n}2\binom{n}1+n^2$, both of which produce $n^3$.

Comment: Brilliant! +1. I was only looking for 3 vertices, and forgot that choosing 3 lines also make a triangle!

Comment: $n^2$ in your second answer is too cute! $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution :

Note : This doesn't explain the combinatorial identity in the question. I only give alternative way to arrive at $T_{n}=n^3$.

I'll use that given $m$ points on a straight line and one point not on the line, total number of triangles formed is $\binom{m}{2}$.

Note, every triangle includes at least one base vertex.  For $n$th diagram, number of points on any non-base line $= n+1$ and there are $n$ such lines.

Triangles including left vertex $ = n\binom{n+1}{2}$

Remaining triangles with right vertex $ = n\binom{n}{2}$

Hence $T_{n} = n\{\binom{n+1}{2}+\binom{n}{2}\} = n^3$.